# VBA Execute Access Query error: database or object read only

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have tried executing this code:

```vb
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strConn As String
Dim strAcc As String

'Connecting to the DB
cn.ConnectionTimeout = 7200
cn.CommandTimeout = 7200
strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=d:\Documents\proof.accdb;Mode=Share Deny None; Persist Security Info=False"
cn.Open strConn

'Creating the query string
strAcc = "SELECT *  " _
& " INTO Table1 " _
& " FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=D:\Documents\database.xlsm].[Sheet1$];"

'Executing the query

rs.Open strAcc, cn, adOpenDynamic
```

When executing it gets the error: "Can't refresh. Database or object read only" on the line:

```vb
rs.Open strAcc, cn, adOpenDynamic
```

I don't know how to fix this problem. Curious thing is that when executing a different query (selecting from an existing table) it works perfectly. That's why I guess the problem is related to the fact that a new table is being created with the `SELECT INTO` command. I also tried writing "Mode=Share Deny None" (as you may see) in the connection but didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your having this issue most likely because the directory the back end database Located at: "d:\Documents\proof.accdb" is sitting within a directory you do not have Write Permissions to. Thus you are only able to read from the DB/ File and not "Write" i.e. perform INSERTS or UPDATES Like you are currently trying to do.

Navigate to and right click that directory, Select "Properties". Looking at the Security tab assign yourself permissions to that directory if you are able to.